# How to fix "relation does not exist"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to run existing Django project, but always get the same error

After running python manage.py I get error relation does not exist. I am using Django version 1.11.11. I think that there no need to be an error with database, because when I downgrade Django version to 1.8.1, there is no errors and migration is successful. What might be the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "qa_qagroup" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "qa_qagroup" LIMIT 1
                               ^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 104, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Vizia_project\banknote\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    from qa.views import *
  File "C:\Vizia_project\qa\views.py", line 11, in <module>
    class QAGroupFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  File "C:\Vizia_project\qa\views.py", line 13, in QAGroupFilter
    if QAGroup.objects.exists():
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 670, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 517, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 858, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 889, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Vizia_project\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "qa_qagroup" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "qa_qagroup" LIMIT 1
                               ^

requirements.txt looks this:
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
Django==1.11.11
django-crispy-forms==1.7.1
django-filter==1.1.0
django-modelcluster==3.1
django-session-security==2.6.0
django-taggit==0.22.1
django-treebeard==4.1.2
djangorestframework==3.6.4
html5lib==0.999999999
idna==2.6
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.3.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
raven==6.3.0
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
Unidecode==0.4.21
urllib3==1.22
wagtail==1.12.2
webencodings==0.5.1
wheel==0.24.0
Willow==0.4
```

views.py from qa

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import django_filters
from qa.models import QAGroup
from qa.forms import QAForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.

class QAGroupFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    if QAGroup.objects.exists():
        initial = QAGroup.objects.first().pk
    else:
        initial = None

    group = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=QAGroup.objects.order_by('pk'),
        # widget=LinkWidget(),
        label='',
        empty_label=None,
        name='title',
        initial=initial,
    )


    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # filterset is bound, use initial values as defaults
        if data is not None:
            data = data.copy()

            for name, f in self.base_filters.items():
                initial = f.extra.get('initial')

                # filter param is either missing or empty, use initial as default
                if not data.get(name) and initial:
                    data[name] = initial

        super(QAGroupFilter, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = QAGroup
        fields = ['group', ]


def qa_list(request):
    filter = QAGroupFilter(request.GET, queryset=QAGroup.objects.all())
    groups = QAGroup.objects.order_by('pk')
    form = QAForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QAForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.send_email()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _('Some text here'))
            return redirect('faq')

    return render(request, 'qa/qa.html', {'filter': filter, 'groups': groups, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Python version is 4.3.3, pip version 9.0.3. The way I try to run is: virtualenv env --no-site-packages -> env\Scripts\activate -> pip install -r requirements.txt -> python manage.py migrate (also tried python manage.py makemigrations the outcome is the same, still get error)

Comment: Can you show your views.py where this error comes from? Whole `QAGroupFilter` maybe.

Comment: Possibilities: 1) case folding problem, missing double quotes 2) bad `search_path` 3) wrong database.

Comment: Ok, I have added views.py. I am new to Django framework, so would You please help me where is the problem

Comment: Solved! I just deleted QAGroup.objects.exists() if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question.

You have code at class level, so it runs on import - before the migrations can run. In your case the code is in QAGroupFilter, where you do `QAGroup.objects.exists()`. That code needs to be moved into a method.

Comment: I have added views.py code. Can You please watch and say what might be the problem

Comment: I already told you. All that code starting with `if QAGroup.objects.exists():` must be moved into a method, so that it does not run on import.

Comment: Ok, if QAGroup.objects.exists(): statement I need to move to external method? Or I simply can delete it? Sorry for that kind of questions, I am new in Django and Python wolrd

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one for help. Solved! I just deleted QAGroup.objects.exists() if statement